# Elasticsearch significant terms aggregation: meaning of doc_count and bg_count

Tags: elasticsearch, significant-terms

I am having trouble finding documentation to explain the `doc_count` and `bg_count` fields in the response to the significant terms aggregation.

For example I would expect that, if I do not set a background filter, the `bg_count` should the the total number of documents in the index. However what I see is that the `bg_count` is not the same for each result, and it isn't anywhere near the total number of documents.

I assume that `doc_count` is the number of documents containing the returned `key.`

What is the actual meaning of these values? Where can I find more complete documentation for that?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and I'm not convinced that the answer is as simple as @Val said. `bg_count` seems to also include deleted documents (it matches the values returned by the `_stats` endpoint)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simply:

- `doc_count` is the number of documents in the **result set** with the given term
- `bg_count` is the number of documents in the **whole index** with the given term

Comment: This is what I was able to convince myself of as well. Thanks.